# Expressions of one-dimensional representations of the group $G=\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & * & *\\ 0 & 1 & *\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}|\in GL(3,F_p)\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $$G=\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & * & *\\
0 & 1 & *\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}|\in GL(3,F_p)\},$$ where $F_p$ is the finite field with $p$ elements and $p$ is a prime. Let $reg(H)$ be the regular representation of $G$ over the complex field $\mathbb{C}$. Then
$$reg(H)\cong \oplus_{l,m=1}^3\sigma_{l,m}\oplus 3\mu_1\oplus 3\mu_2,$$ where $\sigma_{l,m}$, $l,m=1,2,3$ are one-dimensional representations and $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are two three-dimensional representations. Matrix multiplication gives
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & b\\
0 & 1 & c\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x & y\\
0 & 1 & z\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a+x & b+y+az\\
0 & 1 & c+z\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$
so we can express $G$ as the set of triples $(a,b,c)$, with entries in $Z/{3Z}$ and composition rule $$(a,b,c)(x,y,z)=(a+x,b+y+az,c+z).$$
Then the 9 one-dimensional representations are $\sigma_{r,s}(a,b,c)=w^{ra+sc}$, where $w$ is a primitive third root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes. This follows from a computation of the abelianization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Heisenberg group $H_p$ of order $p^3$. Its Abelianization $A$ is the direct product of two cyclic groups $C_p$ of order $p$. Every 1-dim representation of $H_p$ is a (irreducible) representation of the Abelian group $A$. There are $p^2$ obvious such representations.

Comment: Thank you very much！